# Getting started with Tcl TK?

Tags: tcl

One of my modules at university next year is going to involve programming in Tcl tk, I was wondering where to find the best resources and information about the language, so that I am well prepared. I'm currently looking on [this site](http://www.tcl.tk) which is pretty helpful, but the book that they recommend is quite old, and I was wondering if someone could recommend any other books to purchase or if the language hasn't changed significantly since the release of the book in 1999?

Also, what projects or examples should I start working on to make me familiar with the language?

Any other information would be extremely helpful and appreciated!

*I posted this question because I couldn't find any others similar too it, apologies if I haven't looked hard enough.*

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The [Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/) is also a really good reference when you actually hack into some code and forget the name of a function or two.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some of the books I have in my library that you might find useful are:

- [Tcl and the Tk Toolkit](http://amzn.com/032133633X) *(Ousterhout)* - **The** book on Tcl/Tk, and probably the one you're referring to. It's old and some of the information is a bit out-dated, but it is fantastic *(and, I believe, I say that without exaggerating)* at showing how to program in Tcl. It was written by the originator of the language.

  [Practical Programming in Tcl and Tk](http://amzn.com/0130385603) *(Welch)* - The other book on Tcl/Tk that nearly everyone that programs in it seriously has in their library. Brent did an amazing job on this book.

  [Effective Tcl/Tk Programming: Writing Better Programs with Tcl and Tk](http://amzn.com/0201634740) *(Harrison, McLennon)* - Once you get to larger, more complex, programs, this book can be very handy to have read. It goes into organization and the like. This book is likely beyond what you need at the moment, but I mention it because it's a very good read as you get deeper into Tcl.

It's also worth bookmarking the [Tcler's Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/). It can feel a bit unorganized at times, but there's more information there than... well, anywhere. It's an amazing resource.

The ActiveTcl distribution is, indeed the way to go. The folks over at ActiveState are a smart bunch.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the recommendations, appreciated.

Comment: No problem at all. To this day, every time I program in another language, I'm constantly aware of what Tcl can do (and I expect to be able to do) that the language I'm using can't. I guess it's kind of the way Lispers feel about Lisp... I love Tcl, there's power there that very few (non-Lisp-esque) languages can match.

Comment: I second the nod to "Practical Programming in Tcl and Tk". It was one of the first books I bought for my current assignment.

Comment: Thanks for the Tcl love. I used to write lots of scripts in Perl, but our industry has adpoted the Tcl interpreter as a way of providing custom scripting and commands. Now I write most of my utility and config management scripts in Tcl because I'm so comfortable with it.

Comment: I liked "Practical Programming in Tcl and Tk", but I could have used a little more focus on Tcl.

Comment: +1 here for /Practical Programming in Tcl and Tk/

Comment: There's the second edition of *Tcl and the Tk Toolkit* out since this question was originally answered. It covers up to Tcl 8.5. (Disclosure: I wrote part of it.)

Answer (score 9):

Are you familiar with the [Active Tcl](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/) distribution? If not, then this is the best place to start looking for resources and documentation.

Comment: No, I'm not but I'll check it out, I don't have any experience with it so anything to point me in the right direction would be a great help

Comment: +1 If you're working on windows the Activestate distributions are perhaps the best windows-based distros of scripting languages out there.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try [TclTutor](http://www.msen.com/~clif/TclTutor.html) interactive application where you can not only learn the materail but also try it at once.

Answer (score 4):

I also recommend Tcl and the Tk Toolkit. It is great for understanding the core of Tcl, though I can't comment on how useful it is as a reference (I use the online documentation for that). The second edition of Tcl and the Tk Toolkit is currently available as a "Rough Cut" [from Safari Books Online](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780321601766) (meaning that you can download a draft PDF now and a final PDF when the book is released). They seem to have added a bunch of information about Tk, especially the themed widgets that were introduced in 8.5. They also added some information to the section about Tcl, including dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

> but the book that they recommend is quite old,

The fact about tcl is, it is quite old, the book by Ousterhout is still the best book on tcl (and IMHO, almost a classic).  There was never even a [second edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032133633X) although one is apparently in the making.  [tcl](http://www.computerworld.com.au/article/301772/-z_programming_languages_tcl) was a great idea at the time and it doesn't really hurt to learn it, but it hasn't kept up and frankly had a lot of design issues from the start.
   Don't get me wrong, I was a huge fan of tcl back in the day, but it's not the best thing to be learning now.  If you decide to carry-on, pick up a used copy of the original book and use the online resources.

The original purpose of tcl was to be easy and free enough to eliminate the need for the myriad of home-grown command languages that folks were writing to add interactivity to their applications.  Later, the Tk toolkit was added and it was the easiest, free way to add a GUI to an application.

Today, there are a lot more options available (for example for GUI's the [Qt](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/) toolkit is now under the LGPL therefore almost as free at Tk.
   For adding a command line interface to an existing C / C++ application, the closest modern tool is [Lua](http://www.lua.org/), but even more powerful languages like ruby and python are not much harder to integrate with C/ C++ applications (especially with tools like [boost python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) and [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)).

Comment: Second edition of the Ousterhout book is due in September.

Comment: Frankly, I would say Oursterhout's book is far from the best. It's just way too outdated. It covers the basics fine but the language has changed quite a lot over the years.

Comment: First, let me say that I am a quiet Tcl/Tk aficionado, so don't take my opinion as unbiased, but I would say that overall Ruby and Python are no more "powerful" than Tcl, just a whole lot more syntactically complicated, which is not a good thing.  Granted they do have object orientation, which is much abused and is just now making it into the Tcl core; but they don't have a built in event-loop, which is amazing and a feature of Tcl.

Answer (score 3):

An second edition of Ousterhout's book, updated and augmented by Ken Jones, is available. It has a release year of 2010, so the second edition is pretty current.  Also, the wiki page http://wiki.tcl.tk/57 has a list of a number of books that deal with Tcl in some capacity.

Answer (score 3):

Use this invaluable [reference guide](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/#TclTk) or [this more up-to-date quick ref](http://home.comcast.net/~brian199/tcl_tk_ref_guide.html) (thanks to Colin Macleod).

Comment: That's for version 8.0 which is very old.  A more up-to-date quick ref can be found at http://home.comcast.net/~brian199/tcl_tk_ref_guide.html

Answer (score 2):

There is plenty of information on the [Tcl Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/), though it can be hard to find things.  A look at the [Recent Changes](http://wiki.tcl.tk/4) page will show that there's plenty of activity going on.

Comment: Link-only anwers are bad because they become broken over time.

Answer (score 2):

Able to program in Tcl may not land you a job, but it certainly can help you to get the work done fast. I learned Tcl back in 1996 and Tcl is still one of my favorite programming languages in solving most of my daily sys admin work. In most cases, I am able to accomplish the same task when my programming colleagues are still on the drawing board designing the object classes.

Comment: I like to say "Tcl may not help you _get_ a job, but it will certainly help you _do_ the job" :-)

Answer (score 2):

Besides from the great suggestions from other comments, I just have to add [Tcl for Web Nerd](http://philip.greenspun.com/tcl/) by Philip Greenspun, the creator of the Tcl-based framework ACS (which later became [OpenACS](http://www.openacs.org)).

Answer (score 1):

I have learnt it through Practical Programming in TCL/TK. It is a very good. Along with that TCL-TK toolkit book was also very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The most recent book I know of is Clif Flynt's  [*Tcl/Tk: a developer's guide*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123847176).  The third edition was published in 2012 by Morgan Kaufman and it covers the (as I'm writing this answer) current version of Tcl: **8.6**.

I've only had the book in my house for a week, but it looks to be quite thorough and I like what I've read so far.

I own and have read both Ousterhout's *Tcl and the Tk Toolkit* and Welch's *Practical Programming in Tcl and Tk* (2nd Ed) and I liked them both.  But Tcl seems to have come a long way since my copy of Welch's was published and a ***very*** long way since Ousterhout's.  There are some really important/nice things that have been added to the core language/library.

(Incidentally, I also thought the new paperback price was extremely reasonable on Amazon for an almost 800 page tome.)